# NoMethodError: undefined method `seconds_to_utc_offset' for #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using [`time_zone`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.6/activesupport/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb#L194) and [`seconds_to_utc_offset`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-seconds_to_utc_offset). I get these results:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.country_zones('gl').first.utc_offset
#=> -14400

ActiveSupport::TimeZone.country_zones('gl').first.seconds_to_utc_offset -14400
#>> NoMethodError: undefined method `seconds_to_utc_offset' for #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x0000000a0e7a68>
```

Why does it say this doesn't exist when it does? Even the tab completion for that method works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that you're trying to call the method on the instance of the class `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`.

But the method is implemented as a class method of `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.seconds_to_utc_offset(-21_600) # => "-06:00"
```

So you might want to call it like this:

```
offset = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.country_zones('gl').first.utc_offset
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.seconds_to_utc_offset(offset)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was used to Java where all classes (and instances) have access to static methods.